# Setting shortcut key for editing text in QLineEdit in Python PyQt4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

i want to know is there any reference for make shortcut key to edit text in a line edit in PyQt4 python. i have been looking in google for almost 2 day but i can't find any relevant info about this. it's will be better if you gift me code sample. any suggestion would be welcomed, Thank's

Comment: Could you clarify: Are you looking for the ability to define a shortcut that changes the focused widget to the `QLineEdit` so that when you start typing, the original text in the line edit is replaced by whatever is typed?

Comment: @three_pineapples yes that what i want to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creates a `QShorcut` and connect to the function `setFocus()`

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.line = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Button")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.line)
        shortcut = QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+O"), self)
        shortcut.activated.connect(self.line.setFocus)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Before `Ctrl+O`

[image]

After `Ctrl+O`

[image]